# Print file name of including file, not included

Tags: php, httprequest, canonical-link, http-host

I have `example1.php` and `example2.php` that include `example3.php`. In `example3.php` I have:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://website.com/<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>">
```

What I wanted is to have `example1.php`/`example2.php` in `href` dependent on the file *including* `example3.php`. The problem is that of course `__FILE__` outputs `example3.php`. Is it possible to get the filename of the including file, not the included one?

Please don't suggesting using the XSS vulnerable `SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: You could set a variable before "including", then reference that variable. A pain, but it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Warning: This trick may not scale, but will work in this exact case.)

Use element 0 of the return from [get_included_files()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php). That will be the original file that started the chain

inside example3.php:

`$gif = get_included_files();`

then you can do

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://website.com/<?php echo basename($gif[0]); ?>">`

Answer (score 1):

IF you dont want to use any $_SERVER[''] types to get the file name
You can use

```
pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)
```

to just get the filename you want

Comment: Oh, thanks. And `pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)` is not subject to possible XSS vulnerabilities, right? :)

Comment: yeah, sorry it's not that doesn't output nothing, it outputs still example3.php

Comment: yes thats what it does..  thats what you intended to get right?

Comment: No. I wanted to print example1.php or example2.php according to which one of the 2 files was including example3.php :)

Comment: i dont get it. can u further illustrate what you suppose trying to do? :)

Comment: This is what I need: example1.php and example2.php include example3.php which contains `<link rel="canonical" href="NAME OF FILE THAT INCLUDES EXAMPLE3, I.E. EXAMPLE1 OR EXAMPLE2">`